# Nissan xtrail T32 manual gear box/transmission issue?

Tags: manual-transmission, shifting, acceleration

I have a new Nissan xTrail petrol T32, and have noticed two issues.

1. When I change from 1st to 2nd and from 2nd to 3rd especially, it does not go as smoothly and effortlessly as the other cars I have driven (Toyota, MB). In other words, changing from 2nd to 3rd, if I move quickly, is noisy and not smooth and easy (not sure how to describe it better). If I do it slowly, leaving it in neutral for a second it is better, but not great, and I was not used to doing this. It's slightly better when changing from 3rd to 4th and so forth. It's also better when going down from high gears to lower ones.
2. While driving, my stick shift is doing slight movements forward and backward. When I press the accelerator it moves backward a bit (1/2 inch or so), and when I lift my foot off the accelerator pedal while in a gear it moves forward the same way. This is happening on all gears. Also I've noticed that on some gears, 2nd and 3rd, without pressing the accelerator pedal the stick is moving forward and backward itself, when I don't have a hand on the stick. This doesn't happen all the time, only sometimes.

Any thoughts please?

Comment: Are there any unusual noises (howling) while driving?

Comment: I can't answer your first questions but my Xtrail's gear stick also moves back and forward whilst driving. I think this is normal. Kind regards, Jack

Comment: There is no unusual noise, I checked other xTrails and they have it all the same. To me, the manual transmission used is not good, Niissan uses genuine transmission oil, the gear changes are noisy and grindy, however strange is that sometimes it is better, sometimes worse. And it does not really has anything to do either it is from the start of the driving or driving half an hour, in summer or winter. I would like to change the oil but I worry that would void the warranty and I do not know what oil would help this grinds and noisyness to overcome.